# アプリがkill状態で日付カウントするバッジを減らす方法

Tags: ios, objective-c

指定した日付をカウントダウンするアプリの作成をしています。指定した日付までの残り日数をアプリアイコンのバッジとして表示するアプリです。

https://itunes.apple.com/jp/app/atomaru-canri-ri-shuwobajjidekauntodaun/id466693925?mt=8

このアプリのようにアプリがkill状態になっているときにバッジの数を減らす方法が聞きたいです。(上記アプリはサーバは使っていないようです)

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 4):

これは`UILocalNotification`（ローカル通知）で実現できます。

スケジュールを設定した時点で、予定日までローカル通知を埋めておけば、後はアプリケーションがkillされていても、サーバーなしで通知されます。

12/24までのカウントダウンであれば、

- 12/22 00:00にバッジを2に更新する
- 12/23 00:00にバッジを1に更新する

というように、毎日バッジ数を減らす通知を事前にセットしておけばいいのです。